# Legend colorbar is truncated and limits not respected with continuous scales

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors

I sometimes have issues with the legend not showing the entire range of colours when using a continuous `fill` or `color` scale, e.g `scale_fill_continuous`, `scale_fill_gradient`, `scale_fill_gradientn` (and corresponding `color` scales).

Specifically the upper range of the `colorbar` legend is truncated, i.e. it doesn't extend all the way to the upper limit of the colour palette. Furthermore, the title of the legend is vertically adjusted to the (truncated) `colorbar`, and not to the upper limit.

A small example:

```
# set up data, base plot, limits, labels and breaks
# adjust theme for legend just to make the issue more visible

df <- data.frame(x = 1:4, y = 1, col = c(0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7))

library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x, y, fill = col)) +
  geom_point(size = 15, shape = 21) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.background = element_rect(fill = "grey60"),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 18),
        legend.title = element_text(size = 18),
        legend.key.size = unit(1.5, "cm"))

li <- c(0.1, 0.7)
la <- seq(0.1, 0.7, 0.2)
br <- seq(0.1, 0.7, 0.2)

p + scale_fill_continuous(name = "Title", limits = li, labels = la, breaks = br)
```

[image]

Similar for `scale_fill_gradientn`:

```
p + scale_fill_gradientn(colours = c("black", "white"),
                         name = "Title", limits = li, labels = la, breaks = br)

# and scale_fill_gradient
# p + scale_fill_gradient(low = "black", high = "white",
#                         name = "Title", limits = li, labels = la, breaks = br)
```

[image]

As you can see, although the largest colour value is 0.7 and the point is correctly coloured on the plot with the end of the colour palette, the `colorbar` is truncated in the upper range - despite the limits are explicitly set - and the title is in the wrong position.

This problem has occurred on multiple machines and occurs regardless of the palette  or `theme()` options chosen, but I've only ever seen it happen for the upper range. If you vary the upper limit of the colour scale sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't.

---

The following code generates the corresponding issue for `color` scales:

```
p <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x, y, color = col)) +
  geom_point(size = 15) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.background = element_rect(fill = "grey60"),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 18),
        legend.key.size = unit(1.5, "cm"))

p + scale_color_continuous(limits = li, labels = la, breaks = br)

p + scale_color_gradientn(colours = c("black", "white"),
                          limits = li, labels = la, breaks = br)

p + scale_color_gradient(low = "black", high = "white",
                         limits = li, labels = la, breaks = br)
```

---

Can anyone offer some insight?

Comment: Can't you just use `scale_colour_viridis`?

Comment: @Axeman Thanks for the suggestion, I wasn't aware that command existed. Unfortunately it gives me an identical result.

Comment: What is your expected output? The legend looks ok to me, it shows all the gradient of colors from 0.1 to 0.7. The 0.7 label is a bit off, but that's because you are asking it to label the very top limit of the gradient.

Comment: Just increase your limits - even a little bit works. `limits=c(0.1,0.71),`

Comment: I just saw this "If you vary the upper limit of the colour scale sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't."  increasing the upper end by a little has always worked for me.

Comment: @Dan Slone that's what I've always done as well but in my current situation I need to loop through some data and generate hundreds of plots so I don't have the luxury of fine-tuning each one. I also feel a little silly fighting with the legend every time, I was hoping there was an easier fix.

Comment: Since you have a simple reproducible example, and this appears to be a general ggplot bug, you could post it as an issue on github (after checking it hasn't been reported before).

Comment: @F.Evans in that case I would set the upper limit to max(df) + 0.1.  I

Comment: You can tweak the limits with `... + expand_limits(color = ...)` rather than use `... + scale_color_continuous(limits = ...)`. I used `expand_limits(color = seq.int(0, 0.9, 0.1))` and was able to capture the `0.7` break within the colorbar.

Comment: regarding the loop you could just add a percentage by which you expand the limits. sth like max(col)*1.05
sorry @DanSlone , I just saw your comment...

Answer (score 1):

This works in the development version of `ggplot2` (`2.2.1.9000`).

```r
df <- data.frame(x = 1:4, y = 1, col = c(0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7))

library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x, y, fill = col)) +
  geom_point(size = 15, shape = 21) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.background = element_rect(fill = "grey60"),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 18),
        legend.title = element_text(size = 18),
        legend.key.size = unit(1.5, "cm"))

li <- c(0.1, 0.7)
la <- seq(0.1, 0.7, 0.2)
br <- seq(0.1, 0.7, 0.2)

p + scale_fill_continuous(name = "Title", limits = li, labels = la, breaks = br)
```

[image]

```r
p + scale_fill_gradientn(colours = c("black", "white"),
                         name = "Title", limits = li, labels = la, breaks = br)
```

[image]

```r
p <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x, y, color = col)) +
  geom_point(size = 15) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.background = element_rect(fill = "grey60"),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 18),
        legend.title = element_text(size = 18),
        legend.key.size = unit(1.5, "cm"))

p + scale_color_continuous(name = "Title", limits = li, labels = la, breaks = br)
```

[image]

```r
p + scale_color_gradientn(colours = c("black", "white"),
                          name = "Title", limits = li, labels = la, breaks = br)
```

[image]

```r
p + scale_color_gradient(low = "black", high = "white",
                         name = "Title", limits = li, labels = la, breaks = br)
```

[image]